# Controller not being loaded?

Tags: magento

I am trying to edit the reports generated from here, `example.com/index.php/admin/sales_order/index/`. I need to add a new report to the dropdown on the right.

I traced this page to it's controller through the url and dumped the class.
`app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php indexAction()` and got this class `Ext4mage_Html2pdf_Sales_OrderController` so I know it's being overridden by a module. In this case the Ext4mage Html2pdf module.

This controller just overwrites the pdf methods using,

```
require_once BP.'/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';
class Ext4mage_Html2pdf_Sales_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController{
//etc }
```

So I've created my new module in local, hoping to overwrite this as it's in community.
`app/code/local/Daves/OrderModule/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php` and placed in the following.

```
require_once 'Mage'.DS.'Adminhtml'.DS.'controllers'.DS.'Sales'.DS.'OrderController.php';
require_once BP.'/app/code/community/Ext4mage/Html2pdf/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';

class Daves_OrderModule_Sales_OrderController extends Ext4mage_Html2pdf_Sales_OrderController{

    public function indexAction(){

        die();

        return parent::indexAction();
    }

}
```

My expected functionality would be that upon reloading the Sales/Order page in admin, I'd get a blank page, and I don't. Which would mean that my controller isn't being loaded.

My IDE is showing that the classes are being extended, and putting a `die()` into an `indexAction()` method in the Ext4mage_Html2pdf controller works as expected. It's just missing out my controller for some reason.

Trying to hit the controller directly in a browser using `example.com/admin/daves_ordermodule/sales_order/index` also throws a 404.

Should I be trying to overwrite the blocks instead?

I've not created any funky `<rewrite>` update handles in my config, mainly because I'm not sure if I need them, or where they would go. As I know Magento takes from Zend in it's horrific use of xml, I'll paste in my configs here.

---

`app/etc/modules/Daves_OrderModule.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Daves_OrderModule>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends> <!-- same as in the /app/etc/Mage_All.xml -->
                <Mage_Reports/>
                <Mage_Adminhtml/>
                <Ext4mage_Html2pdf/>
            </depends>
        </Daves_OrderModule>
    </modules>
</config>
```

`app/code/local/Daves/OrderModule/etc/config.xml`
    
    
        
            
                0.1

```
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <daves_ordermodule> <!-- this is the class group  and must be lowercase-->
                <class>Daves_OrderModule_Block</class> <!-- this is how you access it -->
            </daves_ordermodule>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <daves_ordermodule>
                <class>Daves_OrderModule_Helper</class> <!-- Mage::helper('squaresphere_module/<helper>'); -->
            </daves_ordermodule>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <daves_ordermodule>
                <class>Daves_OrderModule_Model</class> <!-- Mage::getModel('squaresphere_module/<model>'); -->
            </daves_ordermodule>
        </models>

    </global>

    <!-- How to get to the module from the browser -->
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <daves_ordermodule> <!-- My unique class group -->
                <use>admin</use> <!-- which router class? -->
                <args>
                    <module>Daves_OrderModule</module> <!-- assumes /controllers -->
                    <frontName>daves_ordermodule</frontName> <!-- what is on the url -->
                </args>
            </daves_ordermodule>
        </routers>
    </admin>

</config>
```

---

`app/code/community/Ext4mage/Html2pdf/etc/config.xml` Specifically  nodes

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <html2pdf>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Ext4mage_Html2pdf</module>
                <frontName>html2pdf</frontName>
            </args>
        </html2pdf>
        <emailattachments>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Ext4mage_Html2pdf before="Fooman_EmailAttachments">Ext4mage_Html2pdf</Ext4mage_Html2pdf>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </emailattachments>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Ext4mage_Html2pdf before="Mage_Adminhtml">Ext4mage_Html2pdf</Ext4mage_Html2pdf>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Comment: You've done waaay more than you need to :-)... Please add the relevant `<routers>` config from the `Ext4mage_Html2pdf` module and you'll get an answer from me or someone else.

Comment: Hey @benmarks I've now included the routers nodes from the etc/config for Html2pdf

Comment: Hi Read below article is the best solution for controller overriden http://www.forum2tech.com/discussion/38/controller-file-was-loaded-but-class-does-not-exist#Item_1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have no frontend controllers, adjust your config as follows:

```
<!-- How to get to the module from the browser -->
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml> <!-- My unique class group -->
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Daves_Om before="Ext4mage_Html2pdf">Daves_OrderModule</Daves_Om>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

What this does is add another controllers directory under the Mage_Adminhtml module's frontname. The value from `<Daves_Om>` is essentially mapped to the text node + "controllers", so `app/code/(configured codepool)/Daves/OrderModule/controllers/` - and then the typical route matching applies.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I'll give this a go when I'm back on it. I've shelved it for a few days to let it mature! ;P